# Making password visible in Django forms CharField (where widget=forms.PasswordInput)

Tags: django, django-forms

In a Django form, I'm getting users to input their usernames and passwords like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class ReauthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=254)
    password = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        exclude = ("username",)
        fields = ("password",)
```

Is there any parameter I can pass into the widget method (or something else) that allows the password to be *visible* as it's typed?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use a `forms.TextInput` for the widget instead? or a way to make the password visible via js click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making passwords invisible is literally the *only* thing that the PasswordInput widget does. If you don't want that, don't use that widget; use the default TextInput instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose a different widget to be used instead of `PasswordInput` or just remove this completely.

```
password = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"))
```

## BUT DON'T

doing so will give your users a slightly edgier feeling that you don't have much care for their password's security, and open them up to shoulder surfers

Comment: Well, I'm going to A/B test this. Thanks!

Comment: @HassanBaig - I don't think this is something you should be A/B testing, your users shouldn't have a choice, *you* should assist in controlling their accounts security. Believe me, if some website started to display my password I'd never revisit it. You may wish to allow the user to click on the iconical "eye" symbol to allow them to quickly view what they've typed but thats it.

Comment: Well my one consideration is users on legacy feature phones - an unignorable number of those use my service too. Typing on that is quite cumbersome, so I felt if the password was unmasked, they'd get a better sense of what they've typed. But having the 'eye' symbol is an interesting suggestion: perhaps I can provide this as a feature instead.

Comment: @HassanBaig - I honestly believe its your only option, you can find examples of it in use on the windows login screen, or even [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/L1ugpqk5/1/) which is using something called [bootstrap-show-password](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-show-password)

Comment: Sound advice. And while we were having this discussion, I also read this rather holistic piece on the subject, covering recent evolution in authentication work flows: http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1941 in case interested. Thanks again :-)

Comment: @HassanBaig - Yes I had started to read that too but was a bit lengthy lol. - "when passwords were displayed as clear text by default in an e-commerce form, 60% of people surveyed said they became suspicious of the site, while only 45% identified not masking the password as a usability benefit"